# Listbox with Sticky Headers in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, listbox

I am using listbox with headers. Once I scroll headers also scroll with the list.

I want to implement as same as it is done in Windows phonebook, the headers are always on the top.

Kindly suggest what attributes I need to add in xaml file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LongListSelector` for that, sticky headers are on by default. Here is a useful sample code: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/PeopleHub-Windows-Phone-80-88abe94d.

Comment: Hi Toni, 
I have seen this code, the problem in my case, i don't have the data saved in my phone and i am importing contacts from other phone and getting saved in isolated storage and in present implementation it is grouped under A-Z alphabets, once i scroll up the headers also scroll up, i need to convert it into sticky headers.

Answer (score -1):

Windows PhoneBook implements a longlist selector.

Taken from the links given below

LongListSelector which is actually an advanced ListBox that supports full data and UI virtualization, flat lists and grouped lists. It helps users to scroll through long lists of data. Basically a quick jump grid overlays the list when the user select one of the group headers after that when an item is selected from the grid the user is automatically redirected  back to the long list at the selected point.

it also comes up with ways to manage headers and contents separately and efficiently.

Best Links to take a start with

[One](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api)

[Two](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/the-new-longlistselector-control-in-windows-phone-8-sdk-in-depth)